# Finding CDFs of Transformations of Uniform RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

> Let Random variable $U \sim \text{Uniform}[0,1]$. How can I find CDF of Random Variable $S = U(1-U)$?

I know the answer is $F_{S}(s) = 1 - \sqrt{1 - 4S}$ but I do not understand how to get there.

Can someone please help me explain how to arrive at the answer? I've tried solving for U in terms of S using the quadratic formula, and end up with:

$U = \frac{1}{2} \pm  \frac{\sqrt{1 - 4S}}{2} $

This looks close to the real answer, but I'm not sure how to make the connection. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, if $0 \le x \le 1$ then $0 \le x(1-x) \le 1/4$. Consequently, $F_S(s)=0$ for $s \le 0$, and $F_{S}(s)=1$ for $s \ge 1/4$. For $0 \le s \le 1/4$, we have
\begin{align}
\Pr\{S \ge s\} & =\Pr\{U(1-U) \ge s\} \\
& = \Pr\left\{(U-1/2)^2 \le\frac{1-4s}{4}\right\} \\
& =\Pr\left\{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4s}}{2} \le U \le \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4s}}{2}\right\} \\
& = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4s}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4s}}{2} \\
& = \sqrt{1-4s}.
\end{align}

---

Note that $$\Pr\{a \le U \le b\} = b-a$$ for $a,b \in [0,1]$ and $a \le b$.

Comment: Thanks so much I was able to follow your work and get to the original solution! Just curious how come you chose to start by writing out 

\begin{align}
\Pr\{S \ge s\} & =\Pr\{U(1-U) \ge s\} \\
\end{align}

instead of:

\begin{align}
\Pr\{S \le s\} & =\Pr\{U(1-U) \le s\} \\
\end{align}

The latter way was how I am used to approach problems like these and how my textbook usually demonstrates examples. Just wondering if this problem can be solved if started with the latter method? I tried working it out but I can't get the same answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zen'z In that case, you should get $F_{S}(s) = \Pr \{|U-1/2| \ge \sqrt{1-4s}/2\} = \Pr\{U \ge 1/2 + \sqrt{1-4s}/2\}+\Pr\{U \le 1/2 - \sqrt{1-4s}/2\} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-4s}}{2} + 1 - \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-4s}}{2}$.